# Insert a character at a specific location in ksh

Tags: shell-script

My input is `LOAD_DATE = 20072016`
I want the output as `LOAD_DATE = 20-07-2016`
This is sample date.
Date will come through 
LOG_DATE=echo ${LOG_FILE_NAME} |cut -d"." -f3 
Sample dates "20072016,19072016,18072016"

Here is what I am doing:

```
LOG_DATE1=echo ${LOG_FILE_NAME} |cut -d"." -f3 

LOG_DATE=`echo ${LOG_DATE1:0:2}-${LOG_DATE1:2:2}-${LOG_DATE1:4:4}`
```

But this is giving me an error as "bad substitution"

Comment: @Rahul, this may work for a date 20072016 but I will have plenty of such dates.

Comment: can you please post some sample data so that we can find exact solution

Comment: Date will come through LOG_DATE=`echo ${LOG_FILE_NAME} |cut -d"." -f3`  Sample dates "20072016,19072016,18072016"

Comment: rather than extending conversation here, edit your own post and post your content, sample data to analyze. w/o data we can't help you.

Comment: what is `LOG_FILE_NAME` ? where is it coming from ? where your dates are stored ?

Comment: LOG_DATE will have values like 20072016,19072016,18072016. Now I want to make these dates into particular format

Comment: What is the `cut -d"."` for?  I can see no `.`s anywhere in your data.

Comment: back ticks are deprecated use `$(command)`. Also you seem to have not use this in the first line, in which you seem to be trying to chop-up the filename.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't** use `echo`

```
LOG_DATE=${LOG_DATE1:0:2}-${LOG_DATE1:2:2}-${LOG_DATE1:4:4}
echo $LOG_DATE
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error "test.ksh[2]: LOG_DATE=${LOG_DATE1:0:2}-${LOG_DATE1:2:2}-${LOG_DATE1:4:4}: bad substitution"

Comment: You are using ksh? This i tested on Bash, You may try in bash , it should work

Comment: yes I am using ksh. Let me check it in bash

Comment: it's working fine in bash but not in ksh

Comment: Please try the above comment , in ksh  it should work
`LOG_DATE=$(echo ${LOG_DATE1:0:2}-${LOG_DATE1:2:2}-${LOG_DATE1:4:4})`

Comment: I made the changes like above in ksh but I am getting the same error

Comment: can you share your script.. This i tested on ksh.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's/.\{2\}/&-/' -e 's/.\{5\}/&-/' LOG_DATE_FILE_NAME
```

LOG_DATE_FILE_NAME is the name of the file containing the actual date 20072016.

Comment: This is clearer `sed -e 's/.\{4\}/&-/' -e 's/.\{2\}/&-/' LOG_DATE_FILE_NAME` as the code does not have to compensate for earlier manipulations.